# Prove that if and only if $(A,B)$ is controllable, then $(A-BK,B)$ is also controllable

Tags: proof-explanation, matrix-rank, optimal-control

[Proof that the rank of $(A,B)$ is the same as $(A-BK,B)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YBLx.png)

The image is taken from ["Optimal Control Methods for Linear Discrete-Time Economic Systems" by Y. Murata](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=vHHjBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=Prove%20(A%20B)%20is%20controllable%20if%20(A-BK,%20B)%20is%20controllable%20for%20any%20matrix%20K&source=bl&ots=nVDkFyNpu9&sig=zODdbH4fU0KEvO3YzMR_x9jh6EI&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSmpvA_uDWAhVGwLwKHfIMDCIQ6AEIRzAE#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Could someone please explain why the sum of columns of $B, AB$ and so on do not affect the row rank of the matrix in the above proof?

Comment: To get more attention of the mathematicians on this site. Add more details to the question. Define how controllability is determined by the rank of the controllability matrix for the matrices $(A,B)$ by $S_C = \left[B \, AB \, \ldots \, A^{n-1}B\right]$. If the rank of $S_C$ is equal to the number of rows of the square matrix $A$, then the system is controllable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is based on the following fact (which is easy to show): If $w_1,\ldots,w_m\in\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ then
$$
\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,(u_1+w_1),\ldots,(u_m+w_m)\} = \operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,u_1,\ldots,u_m\}.
$$
In particular,
$$
\dim\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,u_1+w_1,\ldots,u_m+w_m\} = \dim\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,u_1,\ldots,u_m\},
$$
which is the same as
$$
\operatorname{rk}[V,U+W] = \operatorname{rk}[V,U],
$$
where $V = [v_1,\ldots,v_n]$, $W = [w_1,\ldots,w_m]$, and $U = [u_1,\ldots,u_m]$. The assumption $w_1,\ldots,w_m\in\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ now means that $W = VL$ with a matrix $L$ of appropriate dimensions.

Comment: Honestly, your answer is not very instructive. Please add more details.

Comment: @MrYouMath What is it you don't understand?

Comment: +1 for your answer: almost everything from line three onward.

Comment: @MrYouMath Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be (column) vectors and let $V = [v_1,\ldots,v_n]$ be the matrix with these vectors as columns. Then we have that $\operatorname{rk}(V) = \dim\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$. Is that clear to you?